# converting nested MY_SQL query into one view query

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
CashiersInShifts(ShiftNun,ShiftDAte,CashierNum),
Oreders(OrderNum,Payment,CustomerNum,ShiftNum,ShiftDAte,CashierNum),
Course(CourseNum,Name,Price),
CourseInOrder(OrderNum,CourseNum,Quantity),
Employee(EmployeeNum,Name,BirthDay).
```

I want to convert the following query:

```
SELECT EmployeeNum, Name, MAX(TotalSales)/10 AS Commission
FROM (SELECT OrderNum, CS.ShiftDate, CS.CashierNum AS EmployeeNum, CO.CourseNum, C.Price, SUM(C.Price) AS TotalSales
FROM CashiersInShifts CS NATURAL JOIN Orders O NATURAL JOIN CoursesInOrder CO NATURAL JOIN Course C
WHERE CS.ShiftDate = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY CS.CashierNum) T1 NATURAL JOIN Employee;
```

into **one** view query.
thanks for the help

Comment: Please read [ask] : it's really hard to understand what you wrote... You can put your code in the correct syntax so we can read your code...

Comment: format your question and provide enough detailed information if you require help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery in the `SELECT`.  I would advise you against using `natural join` -- it is much, much better to know the columns you are joining on, if you want to avoid inadvertent errors.  However, your question is about your query, so I'm leaving the `natural join` in:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeNum, e.Name, 
       (SELECT SUM(C.Price) AS TotalSales
        FROM CashiersInShifts CS NATURAL JOIN
             Orders O NATURAL JOIN
             CoursesInOrder CO NATURAL JOIN
             Course C
        WHERE CS.ShiftDate = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND
              CS.CaashierNum = e.EmployeeNum
        ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) / 10 as Commission
FROM Employee e;
```

Note that this will return rows for all employees.  If you want to limit the employees to just cashiers, you can add `HAVING Commission IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! and if i want only the cashier\s with the highest commission? what do i need to do?

Comment: `order by Commission desc` and choose the number you want with `limit`.

Comment: but i dont know in advance how many cashiers will have the same commission...how can i limit my result? i need the cashier with the max commission, and if there are 10 cashiers with the same max commission i need all those 10 cashiers in my result

Comment: @user3590789 . . . In a view, you would have to use a subquery in the `where` clause:  `where commission = (select max(commission) from (<your query here>)`.  Messy, but possible.

Comment: @user3590789 . . . If an answer is helpful, you should consider upvoting or accepting the answer (although you do not have enough reputation now to upvote).

Comment: How do i accept the answer? As you said i dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer...